# SymmetricDS - Oracle - Specify Schema and disable Push

Tags: oracle, configuration, symmetricds

I’m neewbie with SymmetricDS.

I have some questions about Oracle replication :

- Can I specify which schema i want to synchronize ?
- Modification are only done on the master. Can I disable push synchronization (i.e only syncing from Master to Nodes) ?

Thanks a lot for your Help

---

i've deployed two servers RHEL with Oracle19c

X.X.X.X is the IP adress of the "centralNode" server

Y.Y.Y.Y is the IP adress of the "clientNode" server

ACF and ADM are schema that i want to synchronize

I would like synchronize two schemas only in Pull Mode (i.e only syncing from Master to Nodes)

Here my server.properties on the "centralNode" server

> #Friendly name to refer to this node from command line
> **engine.name=centralNode**
>
> #The class name for the JDBC Driver
> **db.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver**
> #db.driver=org.h2.Driver
>
> #The JDBC URL used to connect to the database
> **db.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@X.X.X.X:1521:MTL**
>
> #The database user that SymmetricDS should use.
> **db.user=<>**
>
> #The database password
> **db.password=<>**
>
> #This node will contact the root node's sync.url to register itself.
> #The registration.url should be empty for the master node.
> #For client nodes, set the registration.url to be the master's sync.url.
> **registration.url=**
> #Synchronization URL with Master Server IP and Synchro engine name.   **sync.url=http://X.X.X.X:31415/sync/centralNode**
>
> #Node group this node belongs to, which defines what it will sync with who.
> #Must match the sym_node_group configuration in database.
> **group.id=central**
>
> #External ID for this node, which is any unique identifier you want to use.
> **external.id=000**
>
> auto.registration=true
> auto.reload=true

Here my client.properties on the "clientNode" server

> #Friendly name to refer to this node from command line
> **engine.name=clientNode**
>
> #The class name for the JDBC Driver
> **db.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDrive**r
> #db.driver=org.h2.Driver
>
> #The JDBC URL used to connect to the database
> **db.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@Y.Y.Y.Y:1521:SEL**
>
> #The database user that SymmetricDS should use.
> **db.user=<>**
>
> #The database password
> **db.password=<>**
>
> #This node will contact the root node's sync.url to register itself.
> #The registration.url should be empty for the master node.
> #For client nodes, set the registration.url to be the master's sync.url.
> **registration.url=http://X.X.X.X:31415/sync/centralNode**
> #Synchronization URL with Client Server IP and Synchro engine name
> **sync.url=http://Y.Y.Y.Y:31415/sync/clientNode**
>
> #Node group this node belongs to, which defines what it will sync with who.
> #Must match the sym_node_group configuration in database.
> **group.id=client**
>
> #External ID for this node, which is any unique identifier you want to use.
> **external.id=001**

i've installed the Syn table from the "centralNode" server with the following command :

bin/symadmin --engine centralNode create-sym-tables

Tables are OK in the Oracle Database in the "centralNode" server

I've started Symmetric service on the "centralNode" server

bin/sym_service start

I've started Symmetric service on the "centralClient" server

bin/sym_service start

in the log of the "centralNode" server

*2022-09-19 14:48:27,939 WARN [centralNode] [RegistrationUriHandler] [qtp361268035-14] client:001:? was not allowed to register.

2022-09-19 14:48:27,941 WARN [clientNode] [RegistrationService] [clientNode-job-3] Waiting for registration to be accepted by the server. Registration is not open.*

in the log of the "clientNode" server

*2022-09-19 14:49:10,404 INFO [clientNode] [DataLoaderService] [clientNode-job-1] Using registration URL of http://X.X.X.X:31415/sync/centralNode/registration

2022-09-19 14:49:10,442 WARN [clientNode] [RegistrationService] [clientNode-job-1] Waiting for registration to be accepted by the server. Registration is not open.*

I tried to open regisstration from he "centralNode" server

bin/symadmin open-registration --engine centralNode client 001

In the log of the "centralNode" server

*Please add a group link where the source group id is central and the target group id is client

2022-09-19 14:51:37,869 WARN [centralNode] [RegistrationUriHandler] [qtp361268035-14] client:001:? was not allowed to register.

2022-09-19 14:51:54,912 WARN [centralNode] [RegistrationService] [qtp361268035-17] Cannot register a client node unless a node group link exists so the registering node can receive configuration updates.  Please add a group link where the source group id is central and the target group id is client*

I tried to update the node group link

```sql
insert into sym_node_group_link (source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id,  data_event_action) values ('central', 'client', 'P');
```

In the log of the "centralNode" server

*2022-09-19 14:54:16,211 WARN [centralNode] [RegistrationUriHandler] [qtp361268035-14] client:001:? was not allowed to register

2022-09-19 14:54:17,977 INFO [clientNode] [DataLoaderService] [clientNode-job-6] Using registration URL of http://X.X.X.X:31415/sync/centralNode/registration

2022-09-19 14:54:18,325 WARN [centralNode] [RegistrationService] [qtp361268035-17] Cannot register a client node unless a node group link exists so the registering node can receive configuration updates. Please add a group link where the source group id is central and the target group id is client*

Maybe could you help me ?

---

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a column source schema in the trigger column and target schema in the router table.

Yes, you can put the master in one group and nodes to another and then define triggers only for the master and routers that will route data only from master to nodes.

Comment: Thank a lot Boris.
could you confirm my understanding for SymmetricDS
1) Unzip in the master AND the node
2) On Master, check symmetric-server.properties
3) On Master, copy corp-000.properties on engines folder and update this
4) On Node, copy store-001.properties on engine folder and update this
5) On Master, create the SymmetricDS-specific tables 
6) On Master, Register target db from Source
7) On Master, configure symmetricds table
8) On Master, start Symmetric Service
9) On Node, start Symmetric Service
10) Check the logs

Comment: that sounds right. no need to create symmetricDS specific tables, though. the tool will create them on its own

Comment: Hello Boris,
Symmetrics is started on master and Node 
- master is called source
- node is caled dest
But i found any table trough SQLDevelopper in Schema of the user Symmetric 
and i got the following message in the logs : 
WARN [source-000] [RegistrationService] Cannot register a client node unless a node group link exists so the registering node can receive configuration updates.  Please add a group link where the source group id is source and the target group id is dest
WARN [source-000] [RegistrationUriHandler] dest:001:? was not allowed to register.

Comment: Master has only source-000.properties file and Node dest-001.properties file

Comment: You'll need to add a record in the node group link table. Follow the user documentation from the beginning

Comment: Hello Boris,
Tests seems to be OK with demo on the documentation but when i try to configure Central and client in 2 separates servers, I encountered somme difficulties. I add an answer to my questio nfor a better presentation

Comment: What are the names of the central and client node groups?

Comment: They are central and client. I set configuration file in my post

Comment: Any other warnings, errors or exceptions?

Comment: No. Only the following log on Master
2022-09-21 19:45:11,260 WARN [centralNode] [RegistrationUriHandler] [qtp361268035-14] client:001:? was not allowed to register.
2022-09-21 19:45:14,303 WARN [centralNode] [RegistrationService] [qtp361268035-15] Cannot register a client node unless a node group link exists so the registering node can receive configuration updates.  Please add a group link where the source group id is central and the target group id is client

Comment: Could you check my properties files ? I ve add auto.regsitration on my server.properties on the centralNode... No Change :o(

Comment: everything seems fine... if I was in your place I would redo the setup from scratch

Comment: Hello Boris,
i've redo the setup and now it seems OK :)
but, i have add in table syn_trigger the name of the schema in source_schema_name column. I tried with wildcard * in source_tabe_name but i've the following message in the log Could not find any database tables matching 'ACF.*' in the datasource that is configured

Comment: Moreover should I load the data with an initial command reload-node ?

Comment: Hello,
more information :)
I think that the user Symmetric has not view on ACF Schema...
I made test with a single table .
theses tests show that Specific rights are needed on Client Node (Create table, allow Constraint..)
Table is now created on Client node.
I should Identify how populate the table

Comment: Hello,
All isworking fine now.
A last question is due to constraint security : Can I  can I enable a synchronization between cental to Node(mode pull) but the origin of the connexion will come from Node ?

Comment: If the origin is Node than the way how to sync is Push